# System.TypeInitializationException в конструкторе SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Требуется подключить базу данных, чтобы была возможность пользоваться программой и с другого компьютера. Нужно проверять имя пользователя и пароль с данными из бд. Однако появляется ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.TypeInitializationException" в System.Data.dll".

Как исправить?

```
string dirPath = new FileInfo($"{Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()).Location}").DirectoryName;
string dbName = "login_database.mdf";    
string connectionString = $@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={dirPath}\{dbName};Integrated Security=True";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table_dict where user='"+text_login.Text+"'and password ='"+text_pass.Text+"'", connectionString);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text_login.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста, введите логин и пароль!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    text_login.Focus();
    return;
} 
try
    if(dt.Rows.Count==1)
    {
        main m = new main();
        m.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность написания логина и пароля.");
    }
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
    MessageBox.Show(EX.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}}
```

Message=Инициализатор типа "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection" выдал исключение.
  Source=System.Data
  TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Message=Инициализатор типа "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory" выдал исключение.
       Source=System.Data
  BareMessage=Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию

Вероятнее всего, ошибка в App.config. Строка подключения :

```
 <system.data>    
      <DbProviderFactories>
          <clear />
          <add name="SQL Data Provider" invariant="Sql.Data.SqlClient"
          description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQL"
          type="Sql.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Sql.Data, 
        Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
```

Comment: LocalDB предназначена для разработки. Для реального использования предназначена Sql Server Express. Но в любом случае: на другом компьютере установлена эта СУБД? Вообще хоть какая-то?

Comment: Ошибка на моем компьютере

Comment: В какой строке ошибка? Вот здесь `"'and password ='"` поставьте пробел перед `and`.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось!

Comment: Ошибка здесь   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table_dict where user='"+text_login.Text+"' and password ='"+text_pass.Text+"'", connectionString);

Comment: `TypeInitializationException` говорит о том, что в конструкторе произошло исключение. Для ясности включите в вопрос текст ошибки (`Message`),  внутреннее исключение (`InnerException`) и трассировку стека.